# argv prints out environment variables

Tags: c, linux

I was experimenting randomly with argc and argv in c, however this program(try.c):

```
/* Trying to understand argc and argv.*/

#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  int i=0;

  /*
    argv[4]="arg4";
    argv[5]="arg5";
    argv[6]="arg6";
    argv[7]="arg7";
    argv[8]="arg8";
    argv[9]="arg9";;
  */

   for(i=0;i<(argc+20);i++)
   {
       printf("arg %d: %s\n", i,argv[i]);
   }

  return 0;
}
```

when run as

```
./try arg1 arg2 arg3
```

prints out this:

```
arg 0: ./try
arg 1: arg1
arg 2: arg2
arg 3: arg3
arg 4: (null)
arg 5: XDG_VTNR=7
arg 6: XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
arg 7: CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
arg 8: SELINUX_INIT=YES
arg 9: XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/raman
arg 10: GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-FAajwI/gpg:0:1
arg 11: TERM=xterm
arg 12: SHELL=/bin/bash
arg 13: VTE_VERSION=3409
arg 14: WINDOWID=58720268
arg 15: UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstartsession/1000/1775
arg 16: GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-FAajwI
arg 17: GTK_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar:unity-gtk-module
arg 18: USER=raman
arg 19: LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
arg 20: XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
arg 21: XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
arg 22: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-FAajwI/ssh
arg 23: DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path`
```

I was expecting a segmentation fault but it worked.It worked for upto argc+63 and then gives segmentation fault.I tried googling but with no success. Someone please explain why is this happening i.e why are the environment variables(seems so) getting printed here?
If I decomment the code, I get even weirder results.

Comment: If you pass only 3 arguments to `main` but read upto 20 then you have *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: If thou art indexeth beyond ye ole end of the array, why are you **expecting** a segfault? It's undefined behavior, **anything** can happen. By the way, some non-conforming implementations (I know of Apple doing this) have a 3-argument `main()` like this: `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])` where the 3rd argument is an array of environment variables. They might happen to come after argv on the stack or something.

Comment: *Anything can happen*, **anything!?** Like Cthulhu leaping out of a black hole, or my bank account filling up with millions of worthless US Confederate dollars? Hell, we should try this more often just to see what happens.

Comment: @Paul Don't forget the [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)!

Comment: @Paul That's exactly correct. The compiler may decide to drop atomic bombs on your house.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant how about asking for a pizza and a pony? :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I would love to!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Going outside the limits of any array leads to *undefined behavior*. What happens in reality, is that many UNIX-like systems (like Linux) actually have a *third* argument to the `main` function, an array of string for the environment variable. So the complete prototype of `main` on such systems is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
```

What you do when you go out of bounds of the `argv` array is that you cross over into the `environ` array.

It should be noted that this isn't actually in any standard, but it's there for backwards compatibility with old UNIX systems where this was common.

It's also mentioned in [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function), and also documented in the [GNU libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html#Program-Arguments).

Comment: The GNU libc manual mentions this [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html#Program-Arguments)

Comment: @Paul Thanks, added a link to it, at the same time you did :)

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways you can define entry point "**main**" for your program.

```
int main () // POSIX.1 style no command-line input
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) // POSIX.1 style command line inputs  
int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) // UNIX-specific - env. variable access pointer
```

Program environment pointer is accessible in UNIX programs. POSIX.1 does not allow this three-argument form, so to be portable it is best to write main to take two arguments, and use the value of environ.

Now coming to the segmentation fault error occurring in the program, it is just because your program tried to access outside the boundaries of third env. pointer.

Comment: *The C language standard* defines only two signatures for main: `int main(void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`.  That has nothing particularly to do with POSIX (which for most intents and purposes *is* UNIX).  The standard also allows implementations to accept arbitrary other signatures, and there are many more than three that are accepted by some implementation somewhere.  In any event, none of this seems responsive to the question, which asks why a segmentation fault *did not* occur in the OP's specific case.